# Deploying Haskell (standalone, yesod, snap...) in Openshift fails

Tags: haskell, openshift, yesod, haskell-snap-framework, scotty

Whenever I try to create an application based on the Haskell cartridge, it results in the a variant of the following error:

`The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 55c67c940c1e6694ac000017 -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c753' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=137 .Last 10 kB of build output: The server is not running, nothing to stop. Repairing links for 1 deployments Building git ref 'master', commit 6b8beb4 Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org`

This happens for predefined cartridges in the Openshift hub, such as Snap, Yesod, Scotty, and for the cartridges defined in the wiki (https://wiki.haskell.org/Web/Cloud).

I'm requesting help because he application never gets created thus I can't check the logs, and I can't make much from the error message. I tried other cartridge types than Haskell, and they get created just fine.

Comment: Since those are community cartridges ( and not really supported by openshift) you should try visiting the github repo for one (or all) of them and log an issue (if that feature is available)

Comment: Found this in the internets: [error 137](https://forums.openshift.com/jenkins-build-failing-with-error-137). Seems like the process takes too much memory when creating the server. The answer suggests using medium gear as a workaround, but that kills all the fun and ease of deployment in openshift :(

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2396, see https://wiki.haskell.org/Web/Cloud#OpenShift. May be fixed in cabal-install 1.24.